# UploadiFive Forbidden File Type AMR

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, uploadify, uploadifive

I am using uploadifive as file uploader in my application.

I am using fileType: to tell the uploader of all the supported file types.

The fileType: takes MIME Types of all the supported file types.

The .amr file is always forbidden by the uploader.

I have tried following MIME Types for amr files
audio/amr, audio/Amr, audio/AMR and audio/x-amr

All of these resulted in forbidden file type.

What is the correct mime type for AMR files?

Comment: Looks like officially it should be Audio/Amr (RFC: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4867.txt ). Try getting the mime-type of your file from the command-line http://askubuntu.com/questions/3395/how-to-get-the-mime-type-of-a-file-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by peeking into the registry
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT] ---> .amr

The Content Type registry value was missing for the .amr file extension.

I created this entry and set its value to audio/amr.

The uploader is working now.

Answer (score 1):

the most common is
Mime type: audio/AMR

but if you getting error maybe the problem can be in the file or a bug in uploadfive base.

good luck.